# How to ignore empty lines while using .next_sibling in BeautifulSoup4 in python

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

As i want to remove duplicated placeholders in a html website, i use the .next_sibling operator of BeautifulSoup. As long as the duplicates are in the same line, this works fine (see data). But sometimes there is a empty line between them - so i want .next_sibling to ignore them (have a look at data2)

That is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
data = "<p>method-removed-here</p><p>method-removed-here</p><p>method-removed-here</p>"
data2 = """<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
string = 'method-removed-here'
for p in soup.find_all("p"):
    while isinstance(p.next_sibling, Tag) and p.next_sibling.name== 'p' and p.text==string:
        p.next_sibling.decompose()
print(soup)
```

Output for data is as expected:

```
<html><head></head><body><p>method-removed-here</p></body></html>
```

Output for data2 (this needs to be fixed):

```
<html><head></head><body><p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>
</body></html>
```

I couldn't find useful information for that in the BeautifulSoup4 documentation and .next_element is also not what i am looking for.

Comment: I don't get the same behavior when running this -- my output doesn't include the blank lines (which is the behavior I would expect). Is that _exactly_ what you're running?

Comment: Absolutely. I am running python3.4 removeplaceholder.py and get *exactly* that output including newlines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could solve this issue with a workaround. The problem is described in the [google-group for BeautifulSoup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beautifulsoup/F3sdgObXbO4) and they suggest to use a preprocessor for html-files:

```
 def bs_preprocess(html):
     """remove distracting whitespaces and newline characters"""
     pat = re.compile('(^[\s]+)|([\s]+$)', re.MULTILINE)
     html = re.sub(pat, '', html)       # remove leading and trailing whitespaces
     html = re.sub('\n', ' ', html)     # convert newlines to spaces
                                        # this preserves newline delimiters
     html = re.sub('[\s]+<', '<', html) # remove whitespaces before opening tags
     html = re.sub('>[\s]+', '>', html) # remove whitespaces after closing tags
     return html
```

That's not the very best solution but one.

Answer (score 7):

use `find_next_sibling()` instead of `next_sibling`. also `find_previous_sibling()` instead of `previous_sibling`.

reason: `next_sibling` does not only return the next html tag but also the next "soup element". usually that is the whitespace between tags but can be more. `find_next_sibling()` on the other hand returns the next html tag ignoring whitespace and other crud between the tags.

i restructured your code a bit to make this demonstration. i hope it is semantically the same.

code with `next_sibling` demonstrating the same behaviour that you described (works for `data` but not `data2`)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
data = "<p>method-removed-here</p><p>method-removed-here</p><p>method-removed-here</p>"
data2 = """<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>

<p>method-removed-here</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
string = 'method-removed-here'
for p in soup.find_all("p"):
    while True:
        ns = p.next_sibling
        if isinstance(ns, Tag) and ns.name== 'p' and p.text==string:
            ns.decompose()
        else:
            break
print(soup)
```

code with `find_next_sibling()` which works for both `data` and `data2`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
string = 'method-removed-here'
for p in soup.find_all("p"):
    while True:
        ns = p.find_next_sibling()
        if isinstance(ns, Tag) and ns.name== 'p' and p.text==string:
            ns.decompose()
        else:
            break
print(soup)
```

---

bonus:

the `.children` and `.content` also return tags with the whitespace in between. instead use `.find_all(True)` which returns only the tags.

see here for more: [BeautifulSoup .children or .content without whitespace between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021345/beautifulsoup-children-or-content-without-whitespace-between-tags)

Comment: This works for me but I don't get _why_. The documentation doesn't explain this difference: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling. Is it just an undocumented quirk?

Comment: i have no explanation. i can only imagine that the developers thought that there will be need for the whitespace between tags. in any case we have to option to iterate with or without whitespace between the tags.

Answer (score 6):

Also not a great solution but this worked for me

```
def get_sibling(element):
    sibling = element.next_sibling
    if sibling == "\n":
        return get_sibling(sibling)
    else:
        return sibling
```

Answer (score 3):

Improving a bit [neurosnap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28683977/5737533) answer by making it general:

```
def next_elem(element, func):
    new_elem = getattr(element, func)
    if new_elem == "\n":
        return next_elem(new_elem, func)
    else:
        return new_elem
```

Now you can call any function with it, for example:

```
next_elem(element, 'previous_sibling')
```