# Identify next loop-cycle element name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to loop over a list of html element with BeautifulSoup but for each element I also want to check the `name` of the next element of the tree

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="main">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <b>3</b>
</div>

</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

for p in soup.find(id="main").find_all("p"):
    print p.get_text()
    if p.next_sibling.name == 'p':
        print "TRUE"
```

Yet of course this doesn't work, the next element from within the cycle is an empty element. Is it possible to control for next name of the element of the original tree?

Comment: Well, as a quick workaround you can check if next_sibling is empty element, and if it is, then take next_sibling from it again. You can even make it recursive to find first non empty element.

Comment: Also please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241641/how-to-ignore-empty-lines-while-using-next-sibling-in-beautifulsoup4-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div id="main">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <b>3</b>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find(id='main').find_all('p')

for p in elements:
    print p.text,
    try:
        next_ = elements[elements.index(p) + 1]
        print '(next tag is: %s)' % next_.name
    except IndexError:
        print "(this was the last element with tag 'p')"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.